# Change css class for all elements with said class with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, class, styles, dojo

Basically I'm trying to find all the elements with a particular class name and switch it to another. I have another function that switches this back to the original class name. Here's my function that's triggered with an onclick:

```
function showEventsAppliedTo() {
    var myObj = document.getElementsByClassName('notApplied');
    while (myObj.length >= 0) {
        myObj[0].className = 'mblListItem notAppliedOut';
    }
    AppliedToButton.set('style', 'display:none;');
    EventListingButton.set('style', 'display:block;');
}
```

I'm getting an error saying myObj[0] is undefined. Any idea why this is happening?

As a note, we're using Dojo, hence the last line of the function. I know I could easily do this with jQuery, but we're not using it and it doesn't make sense to load another framework.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT

Thanks to the help from  Abhishek Mishra, I modified how I'm handling this loop and found a way to do it with JUST dojo, which is what I preferred. Here's the code:

```
function listingClassToggle() {
    dojo.query(".notApplied").addClass("notAppliedOut");
    dojo.query(".notApplied").removeClass("notApplied");
}
```

Much simpler code and a lot lighter than my previous solution. Thanks for all your help. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You could perhaps loop over myObj using dojo's `forEach`, then you won't need to check for zeros. http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/forEach.html . Also `dojo.query` for css based queries, which would be `dojo.query('.notApplied');`

Comment: I wonder if that would run faster than the method I'm using? The answer below fixed it, but I'm going to look into this method too. That query method might be better than getelement

Comment: I believe dojo's `query` would be more compatible across browsers. `getElementsByClassName` is good, but doesn't work in IE 7 and 8 ;) http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Comment: Good to know! In that case, it makes sense to implement it now instead of playing with it later! Thanks.

Comment: I followed your suggestion and I ended up using this 'dojo.query(".notApplied").addClass("notAppliedOut");
    dojo.query(".notApplied").removeClass("notApplied");' and it worked beautifully! I simply switch the classes in the statements to toggle it back. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should just test for `> 0` not `>= 0`. When the length is equal to zero, there's no element zero.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is it. `0` means no elements left! :-) I was thinking `while (myObj[0]) {...`

Comment: That would explain why it appeared like the function was doing everything correctly and threw an error at the end. That did it, thanks!

Comment: See my edit above to see how to do it with just Dojo functionality instead of running a 'while' statement